# GTK+3 GUI freezes randomly (after 1 hour or after 20 minutes)

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I am developping a program in C that uses GTK+3 and follows - more or less - the MVC architecture:

- The model is updated each 20 ms by calling *model_update* (it does not call to GTK functions) ;
- The GUI is updated by calling *gui_update* each 50 ms by reading model variables.

My problem is that the GUI freezes after a random running time, it can be 20 minutes or more than 1 hour and I do not know why. Maybe there is something I should know about GTK ?

Note :
Access to model variables is protected by using mutex.

Thanks a lot for your help !!

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h> 

void *
thread_gui(void* data)
{ 
    g_timeout_add(50, handler_timer_gui_update, NULL); // updates the GUI each 50ms
    gtk_main();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

gint
handler_timer_gui_update(gpointer data)
{
    gui_update();
    // gui_update reads the model and updates GUI by using
    // gtk_label_set_text, gtk_spin_button_set_value, cairo_paint
    return TRUE;
}

void
launch_periodical_call_updating_model( )
{
    signal( SIGRTMIN + 1, model_update );

    timer_t timer;
    struct sigevent event;
    event.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    event.sigev_signo = SIGRTMIN + 1;
    event.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer;
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &event, &timer);

    struct itimerspec spec;
    spec.it_value.tv_nsec = 20 * 1000000; // updates the model each 20 ms
    spec.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    spec.it_interval = spec.it_value;

    timer_settime( timerModel, 0, &spec, NULL);
}

int
main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{ 
    pthread_t pthread_gui;

    init_model( ); // init model variables
    launch_periodical_call_updating_model( ); 

    // signal capture to exit
    signal( SIGINT, ctrlc_handler );
    signal( SIGTERM, ctrlc_handler );

    // GUI
    g_thread_init(NULL);
    gdk_threads_init();
    gdk_threads_enter();
    gtk_init( &argc, &argv );
    create_gui ( ); // building GTK Window with widgets  
    pthread_create(&pthread_gui, NULL, thread_gui, NULL);
    gdk_threads_leave();

    // Leaving the program
    pthread_join( pthread_gui, NULL ); 
    stop_model( ); //It stops to update the model and releases memory

    return 0;
}

void
ctrlc_handler( int sig )
{
    gtk_main_quit(); 
}
```

Comment: Attempting to acquie a mutex in a signal handler is a very bad idea:(

Answer (score 4):

You should not use Unix signals with GTK. See [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

You should consider using only Glib timers instead (and not use any POSIX timer). Read about [Glib event loop](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html) (used in GTK) and use [g_timeout_add](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) or related functions.

If you insist on handling Unix signals in a GTK program, do what [Qt recommends](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) about them: setup a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) to self at initialization, and poll that file descriptor (in GTK, using [g_source_add_unix_fd](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-source-add-unix-fd) or [g_io_channel_unix_new](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-channel-unix-new)) which your Unix signal handler would [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) (one or very few bytes at a time). BTW, Linux also provides [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

At last, GTK is not really thread-friendly (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43141659/841108)), and all GTK functions should be called (only) from your main thread (not from some other `pthread_gui`). Actually, if you really need to code with several threads, consider having your non-GUI threads also communicating and synchronizing thru pipes with GTK and use [Glib thread functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html) to start and manage them.

You could even consider some multi-processing approach: having the GUI program in one process, and the other processing (multi-threaded) in another process (probably started by the GUI program using [g_spawn_async_with_pipes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async-with-pipes)).

Read about [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). It may help you to think in those terms.

Comment: It works perfectly now !! I use g_timeout_add instead of signals functions ... the performances are not so bad =) "continuations" is so strange at first sight.

Answer (score 3):

You should just stop using signals, threads, and just use event sources of the GTK+ main loop. So if you want to call some code every 50ms, then just use `g_timeout` or `g_timeout_full` if you need to refresh the UI more than once per second (otherwise `g_idle_add` or `g_timeout_add_seconds` are better options).

However I don't see the point in updating your model every 20ms and displaying results every 50ms. You're just wasting computing power, as you compute things that won't be displayed. Updating the model shouldn't be too expensive since you can do it in less than 20ms. So if you don't care about the exact period, just update the model in a callback connected to `g_idle_add`, and at the end of the callback, ask to update the UI by calling `gtk_widget_queue_draw` or `gtk_widget_queue_draw_area` on the widgets that need to be redrawn. It will then compute as fast as it can (so can adapt to each computer performance), and won't compute things not displayed. Using timers you then determine the time elapsed between two refresh. If it's too high, you can use `g_timeout_add` instead of `g_idle_add` to limit the refresh rate by using a longer refresh period.

Comment: I understand now why I had some troubles by calling gtk_label_set_text or gtk_spin_button_set_value from signals functions ... 

gtk_widget_queue_draw seems a good way for updating cairo surface, I'm going to check that!

Comment: I confirm hehe it works !... and it's better than calling periodically

cairo = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(drawing_area));

drawing_function(cairo);

cairo_destroy(cairo);

Comment: Yes, if you're using GTK 3, you're supposed to do your drawing in the callback connected to the "draw" signal. You're passed a `cairo_t *` wich is the cairo context there, so no need to create nor destroy a cairo context yourself. See doc's section "custom drawing":  https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s05.html